# Calling actionPerformed() from the other classes

Tags: java, swing

I've got three different classes, each one is a separate JFrame with their own GUI and each does different thing. In another class I've got my Keypad class, which all of these classes above contain.

That's part of `actionPerformed` from my Keypad class:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String s = CheckStock.stockNo.getText();
        switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
        case "1":
            CheckStock.stockNo.setText(s + "1");
            break;
        case "2":
            CheckStock.stockNo.setText(s + "2");
            break;
        case "3":
            CheckStock.stockNo.setText(s + "3");
            break;
```

but when is like this I can only use it in my CheckStock class and I want to use this `actionPerformed` from other classes as well

Comment: If you are switching "n" and appending "n", you can just append it without the switch to begin with.

Comment: `CheckStock.stockNo.setText(s + e.getActionCommand());` instead of a switch. Or even listed as the default case.

Comment: ok, but what if I want to do that from the other class? can I have `CheckStock.stockNo.setText(s + e.getActionCommand());` and then `Stock.stockNo.setText(s + e.getActionCommand());`?

Comment: You just need an instance of the class to access it if it isn't static.

Comment: Why are you using a static function?  Instead, make it a member function, and put an instance of the class as a member of the object with this method.

Comment: @AgilePro how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each JFrame class you add your Keypad object this way.

```
 add(new Keypad(1)); // For the first class
 add(new Keypad(2)); // For the second class
 add(new Keypad(3));// For the third class
```

Modify your keypad class this way.

```
public class Keypad extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        private int identifier;
 public Keypad(int identifier) {
                this.identifier = identifier;
               ..............................
               ...............................
                }

          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                switch(identifier)
                {
                case 1:
                String s = CheckStock.stockNo.getText();
                CheckStock.stockNo.setText(s + e.getActionCommand());
                break;
                case 2:
                //for second class
                break;
                case 3:
                // for the third class
                 break;

        }

}
```

Comment: Most people would say that the switch statement can be eliminated by creating three classes: `Keypad1, Keypad2, and Keypad3`.  In each class you create an `actionPerformed` method that is correct for that case.  You instantiate the three objects just like above, and the code is more structured and easier to read.

Comment: You are most welcome to post it as an answer. I am open to suggestions. But the OP wanted to reuse the same Keypad class in every JFrame class, that was the reason I suggested this way. If he has to create a separate Keypad class for every JFrame class, then the code would be more redundant, just think this way- what would be the case if he has 10 JFrames, so does he need to create separate 10 Keypad classes which almost do the similar functionality in every class? and even that was why this question was raised.

Comment: so which is more efficient way in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Create a common interface that the key pad requires...something like `KeyPadListener` for example.

Within it, declare a method, something like `keyPadActionPerformed`.  Now convention would dictate that you should pass some kind of event object, but you could simply pass back a reference to the key pad and the value to be appended ie `public void keyPadActionPerformed(Keypad keyPad, String value)`

Basically, you `KeyPad` class would allow other objects to register them selves for call back when a key pad event occurs, something like `KeyPad#addKeyPadListener(KeyPadListener)` for example...

In your `actionPerformed` method, you would notify all the registered listeners that an event has occured...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String s = e.getActionCommand();
    KeyPadListener[] listeners = getKeyPadListeners(); // You would provide this...
    if (listeners != null && listeners.length > 0) {
        for (KeyPadListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.keyPadActionPerformed(this, s);
        }
    }
}
```

This would then mean that it's up to the `KeyPadListener` implementation to decide what to do with the `keyPadActionPerformed` event